# Getting X11 window handle from GtkWidget

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, wxwidgets, window-handles

The  [wxWindow::GetHandle()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a185e6cd7065367b552748cb722651b27) function returns HWND on Windows and GtkWidget on linux. I need to get X11 Window Handle, which isn't the widget itself. How can I get the handle from that widget? I need C++ code as it's the main language of wxWidgets.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like:

```
GtkWidget *widget = ...;
Window w = gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid(gtk_widget_get_window(widget));
```

It is C because Gtk+ is a C API, but it is also C++, so there should be no problem.

And don't forget to `#include <gdk/gdkx.h>`!

Comment: Yea, I should have mentioned C too as gtk is in C and c++ is backwards compatible. What exactly is the "Window" type?

Comment: `Window` is the type of a native XWindows window. It is defined as `typedef XID Window;`, and XID is itself an integral type that identifies most X resources (see `/usr/include/X11/X.h`).

Comment: Thank you. If I include wxwidgets and gdk/gdkx.h, will this type be known for the compiler?

Comment: Yes, `<gdk/gdkx.h>` already includes any X11 header it needs . Other issue is whether you have to include any Gtk header, such as `<gtk/gtk.h>`.

Comment: `gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid` is for gdk2, is there a solution for gdk3?

Comment: @Noitidart In Gtk3 there is the equivalent `gdk_x11_window_get_xid()`.

Comment: Thanks @rodrigo that was it! :)